# Why doesn't this code work in roblox studio? I'm new and I don't know why it gives me error

Tags: lua, roblox

```
local contador = 1 
local jugadores = game.Players
while jugadores > 3 do
while contador > 10 do
    contador = contador + 1
    print("Quedan " ..contador.. "segundos")
    wait(1)
print( "Hay "..jugadores.. "jugadores" ) 
end
end
```

It gives me the error in bold and the parenthesis

I tried to quit the parenthesis but I'm new and I don't know what to do.
Thanks

Comment: Could you explain a little more what are you trying to do? It looks like you want to wait for there to be at least 3 players. And what error did you get in your code? Is this a Script or a LocalScript? And where is this code located?

Comment: What is the specific error you are getting? right now i would just point out `"Quedan " **contador** "segundos"` this is not valid, `**` with a string and a number will not be valid, but if you intended that to be "bold" text in markdown, then you forgot to put the concat operator `..` example `"Quedan " .. contador .. "segundos"`

Comment: What does the error sat?

Comment: I'm trying to print a count when there are 3 players ant the game start, it is located in a script and its in workspace. Thanks @Kylaa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using a Script in the Workspace, it will execute as soon as it is loaded into the world. So when this code runs it will go something like this :

- there are no players in the world...
- is `jugadores` greater than 3? no, skip the loops...
- exit

So you need to have a way to wait for players to join the game before you execute your logic. I would recommend using the [Players.PlayerAdded signal](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/Players/PlayerAdded) as a way to check when there are enough players.

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")

-- when a player joins the game, check if we have enough players
Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    local jugadoresTotal = #Players:GetPlayers()
    print(string.format("Hay %d jugadores", jugadoresTotal))

    if jugadoresTotal > 3 then
        local contador = 1
        while contador <= 10 do
            print(string.format("Quedan %d segundos", contador))
            wait(1)
            contador = contador + 1
         end

         -- do something now that we have 4 players
    end
end)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm so stupid, it was obvious, I was learning how to do loops and  automatically I did this because I thought that it was what I had to do. Thanks

Comment: whoops, I forgot to add the loop into my answer. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - To Concat strings together use two dots not two asterisk.
So use `..` instead of: `**`
http://www.lua.org/pil/3.4.html

Comment: local contador = 1
local jugadores = game.Players

while jugadores > 3 do
 
 while contador > 10 do
  contador = contador + 1
  print("Quedan .." contador ".. segundos")
  wait(1)
 end
 print( "Hay .."jugadores ".. jugadores" )
end

Comment: it still puts an error, I'm trying to print a count when there are 3 players ant the game start, it is located in a script and its in workspace. Thanks